# ASP.Net MVC Scripts not working all of the time

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

When MVC application is queried it will run the code and bring back the relevant data but when someone uses another part of the system to add data a few seconds later which would make the called code bring back different results because the original user is in the same session the database is not re-queried as if the controller is bringing back cached results.  If they the logout and close the browser and start again they get the new results.

How can I make it always re-query the database?

cshtml code:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
<script async type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#SelecteZoneId").on("change", function () {
            var zoneId = $(this).val();
            var vrnUrl = "@Url.Action("GetVRNListForZone", "Check")?zoneId=" + zoneId;
            $.get(vrnUrl, function (data) {
                var $vehicleList = $("#vehicles");
                $("#vehicles").find(".list-group-item").remove();
                $.each(data, function (idx, item) {
                    $vehicleList.append("<li class=\"list-group-item\">" + item + "</list>");
                });
            });
        });

        $("#search").on("click", function () {
            var vrnVal = $("#vrn-id").val();
            var vrnUrl = "@Url.Action("GetVehicle", "Check")?vrn=" + vrnVal;
            $.get(vrnUrl, function (data) {
                $("#vehicle").find("li:eq(0)").html("<label>VRN:&nbsp;</label>");
                $("#vehicle").find("li:eq(1)").html("<label>Is Shared Vehicle:&nbsp;</label>");
                $("#vehicle").find("li:eq(2)").html("<label>Permit:&nbsp;</label>");
                $("#vehicle").find("li:eq(3)").html("<label>Permit Valid In Zones:&nbsp;</label>");
                $("#vehicle").find("li:eq(4)").html("<label>Last Parked:&nbsp;</label>");
                if (!!data) {
                    $("#vehicle").find("li:eq(0)").html("<label>VRN:&nbsp;</label>" + data["VRN"]);
                    $("#vehicle").find("li:eq(1)").html("<label>Is Shared Vehicle:&nbsp;</label>" + data["IsSharedVehicle"]);
                    $("#vehicle").find("li:eq(2)").html("<label>Permit:&nbsp;</label>" + data["PermitNr"]);
                    $("#vehicle").find("li:eq(3)").html("<label>Permit Valid In Zones:&nbsp;</label>" + data["Zones"]);
                    $("#vehicle").find("li:eq(4)").html("<label>Last Parked:&nbsp;</label>" + data["pDate"]);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

.cs code:

```
    public JsonResult GetVRNListForZone(int? zoneId)
    {
        JsonResult json = null;
        IList<string> vrnList = null;

        if (zoneId == null)
        {
            vrnList = DbContext.tblSessions
                                .Where(x => x.CouncilId == Council.Id && !x.ExpireTicket && this.EndOfDayYesterday < x.ParkedOn)
                                .Select(v => v.tblVehicle.RegistrationNumber).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            vrnList = DbContext.tblSessions
                                .Where(x => x.ZoneId == zoneId.Value && !x.ExpireTicket && this.EndOfDayYesterday < x.ParkedOn)
                                .Select(v => v.tblVehicle.RegistrationNumber).ToList();
        }

        if (vrnList.Any())
        {
            json = Json(vrnList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        return json;
    }

    public JsonResult GetVehicle(string vrn)
    {
        JsonResult json = null;

        var endOfPreviousDay = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).EndOfDay();
        var session = DbContext.tblSessions.Include(x => x.tblPermit)
                                .Where(x => x.CouncilId == Council.Id && x.tblVehicle.IsActive && x.tblVehicle.RegistrationNumber == vrn)
                                //.Where(x => x.CouncilId == Council.Id && x.tblVehicle.IsActive && x.tblVehicle.RegistrationNumber == vrn && endOfPreviousDay < x.ParkedOn)
                                .OrderByDescending(x => x.ParkedOn)
                                .FirstOrDefault();
        if (session != null)
        {
            var parkingDetails = new ParkingDetails()
            {
                SharedVehicleId = session.SharedVehicleId,
                PermitId = session.PermitId,
                ParkedOn = session.ParkedOn,
                PermitSn = session.tblPermit.PermitSn
            };

            var zones = session.tblPermit.tblZones.Select(x => x.ZoneName).ToList();

            string isSharedVehicle = "Yes";
            if (parkingDetails.SharedVehicleId == null)
            {
                isSharedVehicle = "No";
            }

            json = Json(new
            {
                VRN = vrn.ToUpper() + ((session.PdParking) ? " (P+D Parking)" : ""),
                IsSharedVehicle = isSharedVehicle,
                PermitNr = parkingDetails.PermitSn,
                Zones = string.Join(", ", zones),
                pDate = parkingDetails.ParkedOn.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy")
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            return json;
        }
        var vehicle = DbContext.tblUserVehicles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.tblVehicle.RegistrationNumber == vrn && u.tblUser.IsActive);
        if (vehicle != null)
        {
            var userData = Council.tblUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == vehicle.IdUser && u.IsActive);
            if (userData != null)
            {
                var permit = DbContext.tblPermits.Find(userData.ActivePermit);
                var parkingDetails = new ParkingDetails()
                {
                    SharedVehicleId = 0,
                    PermitId = permit.Id,
                    PermitSn = permit.PermitSn
                };
                var zones = permit.tblZones.Select(x => x.ZoneName).ToList();
                json = Json(new
                {
                    VRN = vrn.ToUpper(),
                    IsSharedVehicle = "No",
                    PermitNr = parkingDetails.PermitSn,
                    Zones = string.Join(", ", zones),
                    pDate = ""
                }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                return json;
            }
        }
        json = Json(new
        {
            VRN = "Not Found",
            IsSharedVehicle = "No",
            PermitNr = "",
            Zones = "",
            pDate = ""
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        return json;
    }
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and update the title

Answer (score 0):

jQuery caches AJAX responses by default. You can disable that by using `$.ajax` instead and setting `cache: false` in the settings object you must pass in. For example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: vrnUrl,
    method: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        var $vehicleList = $("#vehicles");
        $("#vehicles").find(".list-group-item").remove();
        $.each(data, function (idx, item) {
            $vehicleList.append("<li class=\"list-group-item\">" + item + "</list>");
        });
    })
});
```

Note: Technically, in later versions of jQuery, you can still use `$.get`, but as you have to pass in a settings object just the same as with `$.ajax`, you might as well just use `$.ajax` and not worry about version compatibility.

Comment: Thanks.  This worked perfectly and pointed me to a way of switching off for the whole of my site

Answer (score 0):

Whilst search around for an answer to my question I found that the simplest way to switch it off altogether was to use the below code on the cshtml page which makes it always get the data from the tables.

$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

Answer (score 0):

You can disable caching in the action:

```
[OutputCache(VaryByParam = "*", Duration = 0, NoStore = true)]
public JsonResult GetVehicle(string vrn)
{
    ...
}
```

or for the whole controller:

```
[OutputCache(VaryByParam = "*", Duration = 0, NoStore = true)]
public class CheckController : Controller
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  That is very useful to know.  I have only started with MVC recently and this will come in very handy.

Comment: You're welcome. Often people use POST instead of GET to avoid caching issues.